# how to open a local web project in ios simulator in Visual Studio?

Tags: debugging, ios-simulator

Let say I have an angular project on local, separating back-end and front-end. After starting my BE, I am able to consume my front-end accessing http://localhost:4200/ in browser.

If both my BE and FE have been started, is there a way to access http://localhost:4200/ or http://[myipaddress]:4200/ in an iOS simulator safari, so that I can see my staging result in the simulator?

I know Chrome and any other browser is able to simulate mobile devices in device mode, unfortunately, there are results in a real device that are different than that in device mode. Thus I really want to find a way to see the bug fixing result in an iOS simulator without deploying to production.

I tried to set inbound rule for port 4200 and accessed http://[myipaddress]:4200 in safari in a simulator , it said 'Safari could not open the page because the server stopped responding'. (myipaddress = IPv4 Address in ipconfig).

Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

You may have something in your specific setup stopping you from doing so, but you could just use the simulator included with Xcode, which should have no issues connecting to your localhost address on a given port.

Comment: Is it because I am working on Windows and pair to my mac, I am not able to connect it?